# What did Jesus empty himself of in Philippians 2:7

Tags: philippians

Philippians 2:7 ASV but emptied himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in the likeness of men;

What is Paul telling us in this verse?

Comment: Also here https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81442/how-do-biblical-unitarians-understand-what-some-theologians-refer-as-the-kenosis

Comment: @Steven Owen. Thank you.